# alternative to DataGridView in Win API

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

Somewhere on net on one Blog I read a sentence that is "DataGridView something like Boeing 777, but what is goal when I do not know how to fly.
Before I goo deep in creating my projects I wanna know is there alternative for DataGridView in C#.
Something like jQuery  in WEB api.
The favors things which I am looking for is that is simple for using, if its posibile to be freeware and looks smoth and modern.

Best regards
Admir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fly one person across town you can learn to fly a Piper Cub. If you want to fly hundreds across an ocean you need to learn to fly a 777.

There are many ways of displaying data in WinForms applications; which one is best for you depends on what you're trying to do. If you want to show a fixed, non-editable, non-scrollable list of data you can use a DataList; simple and limited. If you want to add scrolling you can output the data to a scrolling textbox.

If you want to handle a scrolling grid of multiple rows with multiple, resizable, editable columns you will need to move to a DataGrid or DataGridView.

There are many alternatives to DataGridViews; simpler controls provide fewer features and more functional controls are more complex.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented the datagridview extensively as an unbound control in a windows forms project using Visual Studio 2008.  Looking back, implementing this control has consumed a large amount of time, mostly because it is loaded with bugs and peculiar behavior that should have been fixed rather than just 'documented'.  A good data grid control is essential to any application of substance.  I would recommend looking for a third party alternative from a company that is more interested in getting it right rather than just getting something out there.

Answer (score 1):

The `DataGridView` is perfectly easy to use without going too deep.  If all you want to do is display data in a grid, create a `DataGridView` and turn off features like adding and editing rows.  The fact that it's got all of these incredibly complex features is really only an issue when you start needing to use them - and in that case, you'll be glad you're using it.

Comment: The regular ListView is sufficient if all you want to do is "display data in a grid".

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress has a really good [gridview](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Grid/).