# An alternative to DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Does a valid alternative exist to the DataGridView control?

thanks

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778261/alternative-to-datagridview-in-win-api

Comment: Why do you not want to use DataGridView?

Comment: Sure, depends what you want to do! There isn't really enough information here for an answer though.

Answer (score 4):

why not use excel? its like datagridview, third party though, i use it and it works out like a charm..

just put Microsoft.office.Interop.Excel

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot use third-party controls, there is a free grid control at [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/csharpgridcontrol.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

That depends how you wana show your data but for TABULAR data format datagridview is most used and suitable control.

Answer (score 0):

If you want third party controls you can check out either DevExpress or Infragistics.